# Run a method every 30 min if user still logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks, delayed-job

I am trying to figure out a strategy for triggering a method to run every 30 minutes if a user is logged in to my site.

I currently have a method called `signed_id?` which checks if the user is signed in, and I am currently using the `delayed_job` gem to handle some other background processes in my application.

I've heard about the `whenever` and `cron` gems, but I'm not sure what would be best for my particular need. Is there something that works well with `delayed_job` ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could keep a database record for each user of the timestamp that the method was last triggered (the first time would just be whenever they logged in), and have a cron that runs every minute.

You would keep a server-side record of when the client first logged in, and keep pinging (maybe with ajax) to make sure the user is still logged in. You would make Javascript execute an action (that goes to the server to execute your method) every 30 minutes, of course being calculated based on the server-side record of when you first logged in. This count would reset every 30 minutes as well, continuing the cycle.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In essence, I'm interacting with an external site (where a perishable session on the external site is created). If I run a particular call to the site every 30 minutes (if the user is logged in to my site), then the session will stay open.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are server-side settings for how long a session stays open, if that's all you need to accomplish. If you have no control over those sessions, I get your predicament.

I still recommend using Javascript to store cookies and keep a comprehensive record of time that they have been logged in to determine how often to execute this method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with cron it is more flexible and easy to use

[cron on ruby](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby)

Comment: I can find information on using cron to set a recurring task - but not how to do it conditionally on whether the user is logged in to the site or not. Are you aware of any usage examples for this?

Comment: well you can write a logic to check whether you have a active session of the user. and also you can setup crons problematically on the fly